# JS error Uncaught ReferenceError: 'name' is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a html string in my JS function and appending it to my div on an AJAX call but i get the above error, what I dont understand is why its throwing the error for one part and not the other.

```
html += "<td>" + employeeid + "</td><td onclick='getemployeesig(" + signature + ")'>Show Signature</td>...
```

this above works fine but below doesn't and throws the error. Names is a set.

```
names.forEach(function (value) {
                let bs = value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
                let cs = bs.replace('"', '');
                supervisorshtml += "<a href='#' onclick=supervisorFilter("+cs+")>" + value + "</a>";
            })
```

ive appended like this

```
    $("#trainingTable").append(html);
    $("#superVisorList").append(supervisorshtml);
```

my functions are

```
function supervisorFilter(supervisorId) {
    alert("Called");
} 

function getemployeesig(employeeid) {
    alert("Called");
}
```

To note, the html I am trying to bind to is

```
<div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Select Supervisor</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content" id="superVisorList">
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is all created in

```
$(document).ready(function () { }
```

Comment: I could not find where ```names``` in forEeach is defined. Use the following: ```names.forEach(value => function(value));```

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue, i had not added single quotes before and after "+cs+"

```
supervisorshtml += "<a href='#' onclick=supervisorFilter("+cs+")>" + value + "</a>";
```

to

```
supervisorshtml += "<a href='#' onclick=supervisorFilter('"+cs+"')>" + value + "</a>";
```